# Php pdo: Showing topics out database

Tags: php, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, pdo

I need some help finding out how to show all the topics from the mysql (phpmyadmin) database on my website.

[This is how it looks like now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G3FAu.png)

The code for that is:

```
<section class="col-md-4 connectedSortable">
    <!-- TABLE: LATEST ORDERS -->
        <div class="box box-info">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
               <div class="panel-heading main-color-bg">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Topics</h3>
               </div>
               <div class="container-fluid">
                  <div class="row content">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
                       <li class="active"><a href="#section1">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#section2">Friends</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#section3">Family</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#section3">Photos</a></li>
                    </ul><br>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div><!-- /.box -->        
</section><!-- right col -->
```

I want this list to be the list of topics out of the database

[How the database looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4VZKQ.png)

this is my config.php:

```
<?php  
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');

error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_DEPRECATED);
ini_set('display_errors','ON');

$CONFIG = array();
$CONFIG['root']         = '####';
$CONFIG['rootwebsite']  = '####';
$CONFIG['website']      = '####';

$CONFIG['dbhost']       = 'localhost';
$CONFIG['dbuser']       = '####';
$CONFIG['dbpass']       = '####';
$CONFIG['dbdatabase']   = 'tom';
?>
```

What I tried:

```
class Forum
    {
    private $dbh; //dbh = database handler.
    public function __construct($database)
    {
    $this->dbh = $database;
    }

    /* function that gets the main forum board */
    public function getForum()
    {
    $query = $this->dbh->prepare('SELECT * FROM `topics` ORDER BY `id` ASC');
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll();

    foreach( $results as $row ){
      print_r( $row );
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: I added it in the question @holden

Answer (score 0):

Here goes from the PDO perspective:

```
<?php
// Connect to DB
try {
$yourdsn = 'mysql:dbname=<YOURDBNAME>;host=<YOURDBHOST>;
$data = new PDO($yourdsn, $youruser, $yourpassword);
$data->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$data->exec("set names utf8");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
```

Then query your table

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM topics ORDER BY id DESC";
$topics = $data->prepare($sql);
$topics->execute();
$tops = $topics->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
```

Finally loop results in HTML template

```
<? foreach($tops as $top):?>
<h1><?=$top->onderwerp?></h1>
<p><?=$top->omschrijving?></p>
<? endforeach;?>
```

Comment: The idea was to show how to connect, query and traverse the Database info. I guess you can adapt this to your needs. Hope it helps!